# Define operator as function in Python (iteration)

Tags: python, function, iteration, operators

I want to define a function H that makes the following transformation:

```
H(Psi(x)) = Psi(x+1) + a * Psi(x)
```

where Psi(x) is some function of x.

How do I approach this?

Comment: You might wanna check out [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: You should clarify how you want to use your function. Note that your notation should rather be something like `H(Psi)(x) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure:

```
def make_H(Psi):
    def H(x):
        return Psi(x+1) + a * Psi(x)
    return H
```

Use it like this (assuming you already have `Psi` and `a` defined):

```
H = make_H(Psi)
y = H(x)
```

Or in one step if you wish:

```
y = make_H(Psi)(x)
```

Or supply Phi as a lambda:

```
y = make_H(lambda x: 1/x)(x)
```